# Insert into select * - overwrite some columns

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Let's assume i have a table T.

T is defined as

```
create table t(
  pk     number,       -- set with sequence by trigger
  col01  varchar2(10),
  col02  varchar2(10),
  .
  .
  .
  col20  varchar2(10)
);
```

(Before you say something like 'you should consider normalizing your data - it's just an example. Actual table is normalized, yet the problem is still there).

Now let's say i want to 'copy' some rows, but one or two of the columns should get new values.
I could obviously write some tedious inserts like:

```
insert into t
(pk, col01, col02, ... col20)
select  null pk,
        col01, 
        'NEW_C02' as col02,
        'NEW_C03' as col03,
        .
        .
        .
        col20
 from t
where t.col01 = 'qqq'
  and t.col02 = 'OLD_C02';
```

But isn't there any syntax to reduce the overhead of rewriting the column names?

I can think of several solutions, but all of them have major drawbacks, for example:

1) Approach i've seen already on stackoverflow - use pivot to group on 'most' columns - which not only is performance issue on it's own, but also is not exactly what i wish to do (ie. - my rows are not guaranteed to be unique, when pk is excluded)

2) Pl/sql approach : use rowtype and either loop over records, change them and insert with new columns values, or use forall after bulk collect.
Bulk collect would require a lot of memory, so it's a 'no'. Theoretically with limit that would be managable, but that would only mean i've moved my overhead code from sql to plsql.
Loop-inserts would cause a lot of context switches - so it's a 'no' as well.

3) Pl/sql approach: use data dictionary to build dynamic sql to do that for me.
Obviously I would never fall asleep again after that, not even speaking about it getting through code review.

Comment: "But isn't there any syntax to reduce the overhead of rewriting the column names?" - I don't know about Oracle and PL/SQL, but in T-SQL you don't need to alias the columns in the `SELECT` statement: so long as the column count and column types match that's all that matters.

Comment: You can do a one-off generation of the insert statement using the same mechanism (data dictionary) you would for dynamic SQL; then run that as static SQL. Just because you generated it in PL/SQL doesn't mean you have to run it there. You probably don't even need PL/SQL, in fact.

Comment: @Dai in oracle you do not need to do it as well, for example:
insert into t select * from t
is valid sql.
However - if you want to 'change' any of the column in the fly - you need to expand the select anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise, this is probably poor, since it's a row-by-row approach and not pure SQL.

```
DECLARE
    l_row t%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO l_row FROM t WHERE ...

    l_row.pk := NULL;
    l_row.col01 := 'New col01 value';

    INSERT INTO t VALUES l_row;
END;
```